# Search through HTML elements in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to search through all HTML `<a></a>` elements in real time with JQuery.

### HTML

```
 <div id="citysname">
    <?php foreach($get_cities as $place) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'init/place/'.$place->cities; ?>" id="place" class="<?php echo $place->cities; ?>"><?php echo $place->cities; ?></a>
    <?php } ?> 
 </div>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#searchcity", function(){
   var city = $(this).val();
   $( "#citysname a" ).each(function() {
   $(this).not('[class^='+ city +']').hide();
   $(this+'[class^='+ city +']').show();
});
```

I want to search and highlight `<a>` elements if it's class matches and, I want to hide `<a>` elements if the class does not match.

Using show and hide the element doesn't toggle. If its matching then elements shows but if its not matching than all element is hidden when I erase it.

My code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qp4s3op/2/).

Comment: What's your question?  What is not working?

Comment: Yes it's not working well.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Your question is very unclear in terms of why what you have tried is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#searchcity", function () {
    var city = $(this).val();
    if (city.trim().length) {
        $("#citysname").find("a").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf(city) > -1) 
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            else $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });
    } else $("#citysname a").removeClass('highlight');

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/6qp4s3op/5/

Comment: Hi thank you exactly what I wanted. Can you make it to highlight matching element with some color instead of hiding the element.

Comment: Note that the alternative without each will search the DOM twice.  I'm pretty sure the first variant is better.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do it simply like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(document).on("keyup", "#searchcity", function(){
     var city = $(this).val();
     $(".active").removeClass("active");
      $('#citysname a[class*='+city+']').addClass('active');
   });
});
```

```css
.active{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchcity">
<div id="citysname">
    <a href="#" id="place" class="kathmandu">Kathmandu</a>
    <a href="#" id="place" class="bhaktapur">bhaktapur</a>
    <a href="#" id="place" class="Narayangarh">Narayangarh</a>
    <a href="#" id="place" class="lalitpur">lalitpur</a>
    <a href="#" id="place" class="something">something</a>
    <a href="#" id="place" class="hello">hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add `if($(this).val().trim()==='') $('[id="place"]').show();`

Comment: @user254153 can you check the update for this one is more simple

Answer (score 1):

Features:

- Match the first letters of the city, not any letter on `string` city.
- Case insensitive match
- Highlight match
- Removes highlight if there's no match or input is empty

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  

$(document).on("keyup", "#searchcity", function(){
    var city = $(this).val();

    $( "#citysname a" ).each(function() {
        var classCity = $(this).attr("class")
        var matcher = new RegExp("^"+city, "i");
        if (matcher.test(classCity)) {  
            $(this).show().addClass('highlight');
        }            
    });
            if(!city.trim()){
        $( "#citysname a" ).each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });
    }
    
});
});
```

```css
.highlight{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchcity">
<div id="citysname">
<a href="#" id="place" class="NewYork">New York</a>
<a href="#" id="place" class="SanFrancisco">San Francisco</a>
<a href="#" id="place" class="Paris">Paris</a>
<a href="#" id="place" class="Palma">Palma</a>
<a href="#" id="place" class="Tokyo">Tokyo</a>
<a href="#" id="place" class="RiodeJaneiro">Rio de Janeiro</a>
</div>
```

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/g1dbz3go/3/

Comment: I like case insensitive feature. I need to modify a little. Instead of hiding the element I want matching elements to be highlighted. I tried but cannot achieve this functionality. My code is http://jsfiddle.net/y6swdmd3/8/

Comment: @user254153 I'll  add an highlight class, to the matches.

Comment: I want the cities to be visible on pageload ?

Comment: Yes cities should be visible by default.

Comment: and when user types, the match just get highlighted and the other cities still visible ?

Comment: Yes. All cities will be highlight even if its not matching. Only matching cities will be highlighted.

Comment: Check if it matches what you want. Try  typing `Pa`

Comment: thanks a lot for helping. Code exactly work as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$(document).on("keyup", "#searchcity", function(){
 var city = $(this).val();
 $( "#citysname" ).each(function() {
     $(":not('"+city+"')", this).hide();
  $("."+city, this).show();
});
});
});
```